# Scheme Hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: scheme

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal representation by iterating the string index and adding the value to the result by multiplying with corresponding power of 16. I figured out "what to do" but I am new at Scheme so i dont know "how to do"

Comment: Use `string->list` and write a recursive function that takes a list of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define convert-to-dec
  (lambda (in base)
    (fold-left (lambda (r x)
                  (+ (* base r)
                     (char->digit x base)))
               0
               (string->list in))))

1 ]=> (convert-to-dec "a00" 16)

;Value: 2560
```

This uses the [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for polynomial evaluation.

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks.  I will not comment about reductions as the OP can look over the definition of folding in manual.

Answer (score 0):

in scheme "#x" represent hexadecimal

```
(define (hex-to-decimal n)
    (string->number(string-append "#x" n)))


(hex-to-decimal "11F")
```